keepalived not apply ipvs rule
os: ubuntu20.04.6
keepalived version: v2.2.8
config file
global_defs {
    
    
    script_user root
    enable_script_security
    router_id sr
}

virtual_server 192.192.101.241 10001 {
    delay_loop 1
    lb_algo sh
    lb_kind DR
    persistence_timeout 50
    protocol TCP
    
    real_server 192.192.101.166 10001 {
        weight 1
        HTTP_GET {
            url {
                path /healthz/192.192.101.241/10001
                status_code 200
            }

            connect_timeout 1
            retry 3
            delay_before_retry 2
            connect_port 6897
        }
    }
    real_server 192.192.101.179 10001 {
        weight 1
        HTTP_GET {
            url {
                path /healthz/192.192.101.241/10001
                status_code 200
            }

            connect_timeout 1
            retry 3
            delay_before_retry 2
            connect_port 6897
        }
    }
    real_server 192.192.101.167 10001 {
        weight 1
        HTTP_GET {
            url {
                path /healthz/192.192.101.241/10001
                status_code 200
            }

            connect_timeout 1
            retry 3
            delay_before_retry 2
            connect_port 6897
        }
    }
    
}

vrrp_instance data_ka_242   {
    nopreempt
    state BACKUP
    interface ens34
    virtual_router_id 242
    priority 64
    advert_int 3
    
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1379
    }
    
    virtual_ipaddress {
    192.192.101.241 dev ens34
    }
    notify_master "/opt/keepalived/data_notify_master.sh master"
    notify_backup "/opt/keepalived/data_notify_backup.sh backup"
    notify_fault  "/opt/keepalived/data_notify_backup.sh backup"
}

expect result:

but got result:

when I use my app called data_ha writed by golang to firing keepalived in some situation will hava ipvs rule,but some situation not generate ipvs rule by keepalived.
first situation:
Remove the field 'script_user root' in global_defs, this will get my expected result.
second situation:
Resever the field 'script_user root', with the environment variable list bellow will not have ipvs rule.
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
INVOCATION_ID=f4582b71981f49159b86d739350a02b2
JOURNAL_STREAM=9:4265208
HOME=/rootSHELL=bash
OPTIONS=--config=/opt/data_ha/config/data_ha.yaml --log-dir=/opt/data_ha/logs
GS_WW=SA1014JKPW6YVIRD=242
Mode=1GS=db6edefe0589b805
GS_EE=SA1014OWCK4B
MasterIP=192.192.101.179
DaIface=ens34
LocalIP=192.192.101.167
NodeUID=c557a953-80e3-404b-9705-fc6bbd0dbc82
DaIP=192.192.101.167/24
IsMaster=false
ArbiterIP=192.192.101.254
AdIface=ens34
USER=root

third situation:
Resever the field 'script_user root', with the environment variable list bellow will have ipvs rule.
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/opt/keepalived
LOGNAME=root
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
MOTD_SHOWN=pam
HOME=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:SSH_CONNECTION=172.16.1.70 58776 192.192.101.166 22
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
USER=root
DISPLAY=localhost:11.0SHLVL=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=1228
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0SSH_CLIENT=172.16.1.70 58776 22
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
_=/usr/local/bin/data-keepalived
OLDPWD=/var/run

Can someone explain it is why?

       # Specify the default username/groupname to run scripts under.
       # If this option is not specified, the user defaults to keepalived_script
       # if that user exists, otherwise the uid/gid under which keepalived is running.
       # If groupname is not specified, it defaults to the user’s group.
       script_user username [groupname]

       # Don’t run scripts configured to be run as root if any part of the path
       # is writable by a non-root user. Also, enforce the default script_user is
       # keepalived_script, and don’t default to the user under which keepalived
       # is running (usually root).
       enable_script_security

